# Can not resolve import com.yalantis.contextmenu.lib.interfaces.OnMenuItemClickListener;

Tags: android

I'm using this package, but it's not find
import com.yalantis.contextmenu.lib.interfaces.OnMenuItemClickListener;
when in the documentation say that it's rename

can not resolve this, in particular, is "interfaces"

Comment: Same issue here, there is no `.lib.interfaces.OnMenuItemClickListener`.

Comment: No idea to solve that ?